# Table going out of div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem in layout in my spring MVC application. In my app, table which is containing in div going out of it even I set a width parameter for this div. I tried many solutions which I googled but without success. Here is my jsp file, CSS file, and screen from my app. As you can see when text in table is long it's not break to new line (as I want).

CSS file:

```
    th,td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #BCBCBC;
}


#all {
    width: 500px;
}

#tablediv {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

jsp file:

```
    <body>
<h3>All your notes:</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty notes}"/>

<form method="post" action="manage_note">

<div id="all">
<div id="tablediv">

<table>

<tr>
    <th class="widther">Note date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach items="${notes}" var="note">

<tr>
    <td class="widther">${note.date} ${note.time}</td>
    <td >${note.description}</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="chosen_note" value="${note.note_id}"></td>
</tr>

</c:forEach>

</table>
</div>

<div id="addbutton">
    <input name="add_note" type="submit" value="Add note"/>
</div>


</div>


<div id="restbuttons">
    <input name="edit_note" type="submit" value="Edit"/>
    <input name="delete_note" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</div>

</form>

</body>
```

And here is screen:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/203/tableproblem.png/

Answer (score 70):

You'll need to do two things to prevent the table from becoming too large.

1) Set the `table-layout` to `fixed`:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;   
}
```

2)  Set `word-wrap` to `break-word` for td/th

```
th,td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #BCBCBC;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/d6WL8/

Comment: I' m using eclispe and I don't have a "word-wrap" only "word-spacing". Anyway I tried to add "word wrap" but without success

Comment: @caro - I've updated my answer.  Seems like your table is expanding beyond the bounds of #tablediv.  You need to set it to a fixed table-layout.

Comment: Also make sure that you include as many th's as you have tds.  I noticed you had 3 columns of td's and only 2 th's.  It's important that these match.

Comment: Ok, but as you can see I want to make radio button in td wihout th for this column. Thanks for answer, if I have a similar problem I will try this solution. But now for me @fredsbend solution is enough.

Comment: It's a table you're dealing with.  You can't properly have rows with more columns than headers.  It doesn't make sense.  Having a mismatch in row columns from header columns is incorrect markup.  I'm just letting you know, so you can produce proper code.

Answer (score 26):

I got a simple solution, hope it may help somebody someday.

Any table  which is flowing out of its container, just encapsulate it with a `div` tag with `style="overflow:auto"`

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
<table>
.
.
.
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer by hoooman is correct but maybe you mean something else. You can use overflow:auto on that table and also specify a width and it will create scroll bars if the content goes outside of the table.

There is also overflow-x and overflow-y to specify which axis.

Comment: Yes, overflow works, and I think this is the best solution for long string :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is long strings of text, like a URL, you can use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

this will break the text "wrapped" at the end of the column instead of like **break-word** which doesn't work out of the box without spaces (**e.g long url's**)

and add:

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

this will prevent the overflowing text from overlapping the next row

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have 1 word that is about 100 character long, try putting a space in the middle of that and it should fix itself.

Comment: I believe the question was related to how to handle the long string.  I don't think simply adding a space is a proper solution.

Comment: Yes, adding space is working, but like Axel said, it's not good solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

set `max-width` along with `word-wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Some times adding a Table inside a Div it happens.
In my case i had given padding-right:0px for the `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue , added this class in css and fixed
    table {
    margin-left:0
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I have a simpler method.

**Just add this**:

```
th, td {
    word-break: break-word; /*or you can use word-break:break-all*/
    min-width: 50px; /*set min-width as needed*/
}
```

the **min-width** for `th` or `td` will not work if your `table` already set to `table-layout:fixed`. Just delete it.

or add this if you cannot find old css for `table-layout`

```
table {
    table-layout:unset !important;
}
```

make sure you give an additional **class** / **id** before the table if you want the code to work only on the page you want.

**Example**:

```
.entry-content table {
    table-layout: unset !important;
}
.entry-content th, .entry-content td {
    word-break: break-word;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

Hope it can help all of you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution, after failing with all others.

The `table` to scroll should be inside a `div`, with `position: relative` on the `div`.

The `table` has `width: 100%; height: 100%;`.

The `thead` of the `table` should have `inset-block-start: 0; position: sticky;`.

The `tfoot` of the `table` should have `inset-block-end: 0; position: sticky;`.

The `td` and `th` in `thead` and `tfoot` should have `opacity: 1; background-color: your-choice`.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the cell values which are part of the table go out of the table.

After trying multiple options given above, **reducing the table width to 90% solved the issue.**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: that is not reducing the width of the table, but setting the width, the width of a table by default is according to content, but it is absolutely good to set the width of the table too before adjusting the columns to have control over it all, so could be a solution for anyone who forgot