# Table is output outside of parent div border?

Tags: php, html, css

I am outputting two tables inline with a parent div just surrounding the content with a border. Both tables are output from a form submission that then generates the tables and outputs them using PHP. When the tables output, both are inline, however, they are outside of the bottom border of the parent div. I want them to both be output and be within the parent div's border but I can't seem to do it. I've tried using display, overflow and height properties but nothing seems to work. The following is my code and current output.

Code in HTML body:

```
    <div class="main-body">
    <form id="formFilter" method="POST" action="portal.php">
    <label for="dateInp">Search a Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="dateInp" value="yyyy-mm-dd" min="2022-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    //Run function to create table if user has applied filter. If not then to load all data.
    if(isset($_POST['dateInp'])) {
    echo filterTable($conn);
    } else {
    echo createTable($conn);
    }
    ?>

    </div>
```

PHP function called that generates and returns tables:

[image]

External stylesheet code for parent div:

```
    .main-body {
            border-style: solid;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
```

This is the output i'm getting:

[image]

I need both tables to just be within the border that it is currently displaying outside of, but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help is very appreciated thank you!

I have tried using:

```
     display:inline-block;overflow:scroll;height: fit-content;
```

Nothing seems to work for me. I was hoping that the content would be output within the border instead it is just outside of it, with the top of the table bordering the bottom width of the parent that it should be within.

Comment: `filterTable()` doesn't return the table, it echoes it itself. You shouldn't use `echo` when calling it.

Comment: Post the function code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: can you add some more CSS? I feel like maybe the black border is for the form, and not for the div

Comment: Your output shows two tables, but the code only generates one.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466528/table-going-out-of-div) hold the answer for you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks to everyone for the suggestions, the post from tola suggested using 'overflow: auto' on the parent div, which worked!